# Implication of this "Bootstrap" technique

Tags: bootstrap

I am reviewing someone else's work and I know enough about bootstrapping and statistics to know that something is fishy but I do not know enough to say it is wrong (or correct!).

The developer computes a quantity of interest via a numerical integral with the trapezoidal rule. For the sake of simplicity, it is 1D with `x` and `f`. In Python terms (though this is *not* restricted to Python), `qoi = np.trapz(f,x)`.

I have no problem with that. But for each bootstrap resample, the developer will take `N` x `(x_i,f_i)` pairs with replacement and then do the integral. Here is my problem: when you take the integral, since you have replacement, any repeated items will have zero width and not contribute! It is as if instead of resampling, you are randomly subsampling with a random number of the items!

That sounds a lot more like jacknife to me than bootstrap. But it is also an odd form of jacknife since the number you hold out is random based on the resampling.

So I guess my question is, is this wrong? It is valid to call it bootstrapping? Is there a better name and/or description?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Justin Winokur.

Comment: What is the goal here? Why does the developer use bootstrapping to estimate an integral? Where do the N pairs come from?

Comment: The bootstrap is to estimate the confidence interval on the integral. It is a random sample: either LHS or pure MC. I am not sure